# Pulsar 220 ground clearance

Tags: pulsar

My bike literally hits all speeds breakers which discomforts my ride. The main stand is the culprit. Is it a problem for all such pulsars or mine is faulty one?
What shall I do?

Comment: approach the speed bump at an angle... that way it will change the effective height as one or more wheels will be on the speed bump longer.

Comment: you should follow what Shobin said, although pulsar 220 is heavy and its suspensions are soft it unlikely to hit all the speed breakers, before doing any expensive suspension replacement just go out and compare your ride height with other 220s around

Comment: @Nilabja the workshop manual should specify the correct ride heights - probably more accurate than relying on another example that may have been abused etc...

Comment: @Solar Mike i completely agree with you, could have thought about that before, I have so much to learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bajaj Pulsar 220 does not generally scrape the road in case of a bump or pothole, with the limited information you are providing I can come to a conclusion of possible issues.

1. Main Center Stand **Spring** Lost its tension which might be causing it to stoop a bit more than its original factory position.
2. You might be driving a bit fast with or without a pillion, since the pulsar has a soft suspension setup, riding fast or with a pillion will tend to scrape the underside of your motorcycle.
3. Unlikely, but there is a chance your rear shocks might be shot.

What you can do is either slow down during a speed breaker or approach it at an angle as 'Solar Mike' suggested.